# Error 100 schedule a post on Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, api, post, schedule

I've used the following code. It works fine without 'scheduled_publish_time', otherwise I get this error "(#100) You cannot specify a scheduled publish time on a published post".
I've previously registered my app with another piece of code. It's so weird.

```
include_once("inc/facebook.php"); //include facebook SDK

$appId = '21xxxxxxxxxxx'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret = '6b8f4bxxxxxxxxxxxxxd56'; // Facebook App Secret
$return_url = 'http://localhost:8888/...';  //return url (url to script)
$homeurl = 'http://localhost:8888/...'; //return to home
$fbPermissions = 'publish_stream,manage_pages';  //Required facebook permissions

//Call Facebook API
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $appId,
  'secret' => $appSecret,
  'cookie' => true,
  'fileUpload' => true
));

    $accounts = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
$PAGE_ID = get_option('fb_post_cron_page'); // it is an option saved in WordPress

foreach($accounts['data'] as $account){
  if($account['id'] == $PAGE_ID){
    $ACCESS_TOKEN = $account['access_token'];
    }
}

$post_url = '/'.$PAGE_ID.'/photos';
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); 
$upload_dir= $upload_dir['path'];


$timezone= 'Europe/Rome';
$date = new DateTime($dateStr, new DateTimeZone($timezone));

//posts message on page statues 
$args = array(
    'access_token' => $ACCESS_TOKEN,
    'source' => '@' . $image_abs_path,
    'message' => $post_message,
    'published' => true,
    'scheduled_publish_time' => $date->getTimestamp()
);

try {
    $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $args );
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

you have to set 'published' to false

```
$args = array(
    'access_token' => $ACCESS_TOKEN,
    'source' => '@' . $image_abs_path,
    'message' => $post_message,
    'published' => false,
    'scheduled_publish_time' => $date->getTimestamp()
);
```